# When users upload photos, they go to Storage but not to Realtime Database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my app users have to upload a photo. Everything works fine, but the problem comes in Firebase. When users post the photo and the description it should go to the Realtime Database with description, postImage, publisher and postId. Instead the image goes to a folder in Storage. If someone has any idea where the problem could be, I'd be glad to know. Thank you in advance!
Here is the code for uploading the photo:

```
AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var myUrl = ""
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private var storagePostPicRef: StorageReference? = null
    companion object {
        val pickImage = 100
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

        storagePostPicRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Posts Pictures")

        var savePostBtn = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.save_post_btn)

        savePostBtn.setOnClickListener { uploadImage() }
        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(gallery, AccountSettingsActivity.pickImage)
    }



    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        var postpic = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_post)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == AccountSettingsActivity.pickImage) {
            imageUri = data?.data
            postpic.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }

    }
    private fun uploadImage() {
        val description = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.location_post)
        when {
            imageUri == null -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            TextUtils.isEmpty(description.text.toString())-> Toast.makeText(this, "Please write user name first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            else -> {
                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                progressDialog.setTitle("Adding New Post")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, we are adding your post...")
                progressDialog.show()

                val fileRef = storagePostPicRef!!.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
                var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
                uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>{ task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        task.exception?.let {
                            throw it
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl
                })
                    .addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<Uri> { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val downloadUrl = task.result
                        myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
                        val postId = ref.push().key
                        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_profile_frag)
                        val description = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.location_post)
                        val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        postMap["postid"] = postId!!
                        postMap["description"] = description.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
                        postMap["postimage"] = myUrl

                        ref.child(postId).updateChildren(postMap)

                        Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Post upload successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@AddActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                } )

            }
        }
}}
```

Comment: "the image goes to a folder in Storage" That sounds like the expected behavior, given that you call `uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)`, which is the API call to upload a file to Cloud Storage through Firebase. It also seems like the correct approach, since Realtime Database only natively supports JSON data types, which does not include binary data.

Comment: Outside of that, none of your code seems to be handle the case of a task failure. Whenever you have `if (task.isSuccessful) {`, you should also have an `else` block where you handle such failures, for example by logging `task.exception` and checking what the root cause of the failure is.

Comment: Have you tried Frank van Puffelen's recommendations?

Comment: Besides that, f you consider trying to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: Yes, but I want the postId, description, publisher and the image url to go to the Realtime Database but can't understand why.